# Excel очистка книги

Tags: c#, excel

Я открываю книгу, работаю с ней, потом закрываю, сохраняю все хорошо.
А вот такой вопрос, а если я в ней что то записал и мне нужно чтобы сохранились в новом excel файле только записанные результаты!!

Как понимаю есть два варианта.
1) Это через SaveAs. Создать копию книги, каким то образом ее очистить,записать, сохранить.
2) Создать новую книгу и туда записать.

Проблема в том, я не знаю как создать новую книгу, а если это слишком громоздко. То существует ли какой то метод который очищает все ячейки книги или придется писать свой ?

В документации ничего не нашел толкового, может невнимательно конечно посмотрел.

Спасибо!

Comment: можно выделить всё и очистить

Comment: не подскажите, как выделить ?

Comment: Работа их Excel или сторонних программ? Как сохранять? В тех же ячейках? В одном диапазоне? Для чего сохранять только введенные данные? Может быть, создать реестр изменений: при изменении в книге данные дописываются в реестр? Но если  правок много, то и реестр распухнет... Непонятна конечная цель, а без этого что-то советовать - пальцем в небо...

Answer (score 1):

Новая книга:

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;

void toexel()
{
    string FileName; // путь к Excel файлу

    // Создание новой книги
    var workbook = new XLWorkbook(FileName);
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Новая книга");
    // Работа с книгой       
    worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Value = "Запись в ячейке 1 1";
    //
    worksheet.Columns().AdjustToContents();
    workbook.Save();
    MessageBox.Show("Завершено");
}
```

Очистить книгу:

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;

void clearexel()
{
    string FileName; // путь к Excel файлу        

    var workbook = new XLWorkbook(FileName);
    workbook.Worksheet("Название книги").Clear();
    workbook.Save();
    MessageBox.Show("Завершено");
}
```